# Manifest validation error when trying to create an app package with firewallRules defined in the manifest

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have an UWP project that runs fine locally, but when I try to create an app package it fails with following error:

```
MakeAppx : error : Manifest validation error: Line 76, Column 31, Reason: The file name "Ambiorix.UWP\Ambiorix.UWP.exe" declared for element "*[local-name()='Extensions']/*[local-name()='Extension']/*[local-name()='FirewallRules']" doesn't exist in the package.
```

This started when adding the folowing to the manifest:

```
<Extensions>
<desktop2:Extension Category="windows.firewallRules">
  <desktop2:FirewallRules Executable="Ambiorix.UWP/Ambiorix.UWP.exe">
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="TCP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="80" LocalPortMax="80" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="TCP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="8080" LocalPortMax="8080" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="TCP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="4530" LocalPortMax="4533" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="UDP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="4530" LocalPortMax="4533" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="TCP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="5055" LocalPortMax="5058" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="UDP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="5055" LocalPortMax="5058" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="TCP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="9091" LocalPortMax="9093" />
    <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="UDP" Profile="all" LocalPortMin="9091" LocalPortMax="9093" />
  </desktop2:FirewallRules>
</desktop2:Extension>
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: It seems to be caused by the path. I dragged an .exe file under the project and declared the executable as `desktop2:FirewallRules Executable="My.exe"`, it worked well. So first please check if your .exe file path is correct.

Comment: But then what should it be? I guess the path is different for when running it locally compared to when making a package, but I don't know what it will be.

Comment: To be clear, I'm making an UWP package, as far as I understand, there isn't really an exe to link to. So what should I set as path?

Comment: Accoding to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop2-firewallrules) I don't have to specify the path, but when I do that, it won't even compile the app

Comment: Which directory did you put this Ambiorix.UWP.exe in your project? Can you show the path about it?

Comment: I'm  not sure what you're asking, I don't put the exe anywhere. We create an app package for the store, and I guess that creates an exe, but I don't really know where. I searched for "Ambiorix.UWP.exe" in my project folder, but it finds it 29 times, all in different locations (like in D:\projects\Ambiorix\Ambiorix\Ambiorix.Package\bin\x64\Debug\AppX, and D:\projects\Ambiorix\Ambiorix\Ambiorix.UWP\bin\x64\Debug\Core, etc.)

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. So this exe is the executable file of your current application? If it is, please try to define Executable as `Executable="Ambiorix.UWP.exe"`.

Comment: What? Did you even read my comment?